# AXI Burst calculations

Tags: verilog

In AXI channel the no. of data transfers in a single burst are called as beats.

size[2:0] - no. of bytes to be transfered in one beat.
but here actual bus size = 2 ^ size

eg:- if size = 100(binary)
bus size = 2 ^ 4 = 16.

also I have byte_count[15:0] - total no. of bytes to be transferred in the entire transfer.

Now I have the issue how to calculate burst length and no. of bursts to be issued.
burst length  is no. of beats transferred in one burst.
the formulas are

no. of beats = byte_count / size

no. of bursts to be issued = no. of beats / 16

16 - because in 1 AXI burst you can have at max 16 beats only.

I am doing the coding in verilog.
This is for AXI Master and unaligned transfers are not supported.
Any hardware design or a formula  is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

A few comments on what you have, assuming this is a master:

You're calculating the number of bursts when you probably don't need to. Usually you would keep track of only the bytes/words remaining to transfer and decrement as transactions complete. Keep in mind you can't burst across certain address boundaries which may require you to split transfers.

You're basing calculations on using 16-beat bursts(maximum LENGTH) but you may not be able to assume this. While AXI requires that slaves respond to all transfers, it does not require that they accept all of them. For instance, an AXI slave for a FIFO interface may reject unaligned transfers. If the target system may include slaves or bus fabrics that you don't know the capabilities of, you'll need to handle some programmable values.

Answer (score 0):

The no. of beats = no. of read or write transfers ie.,
if AWlen or ARlen is 3, then Burst length is awlen (or) arlen + 1.

Therefore, AWlen + 1 => 3 + 1 => 4 transfers or 4 beats.

Maximum no.of beats in AXI protocol are 16 burst length size is 4 bits so that only maximum possible beats occured are 16.

hope you cleared with the concept of calculation of no. of beats.
Thankyou.